# Paypal Express review page buttons not working

Tags: magento-enterprise, paypal-express

I have one weird issue using `Paypal Express Checkout`.
When the paypal redirect back to Mangeto on `paypal/express/review` page , it do not allow me to  place order, the Place order button is showing disable and no action clicking on "update order data" button .

I trace the code and I found that  on file `skin/theme/default/js/checkout/review.js`
line number  144 its always pass the value true . i.e. the `validateform` is always returning false.

```
this._updateOrderSubmit(!this._validateForm());
```

I check with the form and all the data are added correctly.
Its not showing any error as well.
Its also not showing any error if i remove any require field value .

FYI , we have not added billing agreement checkbox on the form.

What could be the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a same kind of issue and fixed with [this tweaking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720234/magento-1-7-place-order-disabled-by-default-in-paypal-express-review). However, seems like this is the bug, I am awaiting response from magento team on this.

1. find file "template/paypal/review.phtml" ... if you don't have this
   file in your theme, just copy it from the base theme
2. Add add the
   lines of code after //Workaround to unbind the event listeners for
   the agreement checkboxes at the bottom of the file. Take the code
   from here: https://gist.github.com/4503260